# Isekai manga where the main character is born as a magic user, but in a poor noble family

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

I remember that in the first chapters, the parents hold a party with other nobles and the main character is impressed by all the meat and luxury, but the very next day, they are eating basically a water soup and all of the glamor is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, can you tell us anything else about the plot? For example, did the main character get into any fights or adventures? And were there any other notable characters aside from the MC and his family?

Comment: Also, I notice that you didn't actually specify whether the MC is male or female.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds exactly like Episode 1 of "[*The 8th son? Are you kidding me?*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/38830/Hachi-nan_tte_Sore_wa_Nai_deshou) which is also available in light novel and manga formats.

The main character is a Japanese salaryman, who wakes up in another world as a 5 year old kid named Wendelin von Benno Baumeister. He is in the middle of a lavish wedding of one of his brothers, but the very next day he realizes that they are quite poor and this was only to show off to guests. They are now eating dry bread and clear soup.

Overall plot is about how he discovers he is very gifted at magic and slowly improves his own noble status as well as the lives of those around him.

Comment: Brooooo thank u sm, I was dying trying to remember the name

Comment: @ShakeJum: If you could, don't forget to click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to officially accept this. Both you and TheGamer007 will get points.